# How do I calculate the difference in time between a start time of a shift and an end time from the previous day?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I need to calculate the amount of hours an employee rested between shifts.

In our database we store Timesheets (LogData) and Jobs(BookingSessions). I need to find the earliest time an employee started a timesheet or a job on a day (so essentially when they started their shift) and calculate how many hours it has been since their last shift finished (so when the timesheet or job on the previous day finished).

Here is my stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportEmployeeRestHours] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @dtFrom DATETIME,
    @dtTo DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
    EmployeeName,
    WorkerReferenceID,
    WorkDate,
    MIN(BookingStart) AS MinBookingStartTime,
    MAX(BookingEnd) AS MaxBookingEndTime,
    MIN(LogStart) AS MinLogStartTime,
    MAX(LogEnd) AS MaxLogEndTime,
    ISNULL(
        CASE
            WHEN MIN(BookingStart) IS NOT NULL AND (MIN(LogStart) IS NULL OR MIN(BookingStart) < MIN(LogStart)) THEN MIN(BookingStart)
            ELSE MIN(LogStart)
        END, MIN(BookingStart)
    ) AS MinStartTime,
    ISNULL(
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(BookingEnd) IS NOT NULL AND (MAX(LogEnd) IS NULL OR MAX(BookingEnd) > MAX(LogEnd)) THEN MAX(BookingEnd)
            ELSE MAX(LogEnd)
        END, MAX(BookingEnd)
    ) AS MaxEndTime
FROM (
    
    SELECT
            Employees.Forename + ' ' + Employees.Surname AS EmployeeName,
            Employees.WorkerReferenceID,
            BookingSessions.JobStartDT AS WorkDate,
            -- Gets the date from the Job Start. Gets the time from the employee start time/ end time. Combines them.
            CONVERT(datetime, BookingSessions.JobStartDT + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, BookingSessionEmployees.StartTime, 108)) AS BookingStart,
            CONVERT(datetime, BookingSessions.JobStartDT + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, BookingSessionEmployees.EndTime, 108)) AS BookingEnd,
            NULL AS LogStart,
            NULL AS LogEnd
        FROM Employees
        INNER JOIN BookingSessionEmployees ON Employees.EmployeeID = BookingSessionEmployees.EmployeeID
        INNER JOIN BookingSessionLocationTasks ON BookingSessionEmployees.BookingSessionLocationTaskID = BookingSessionLocationTasks.BookingSessionLocationTaskID
        INNER JOIN BookingSessions ON BookingSessionLocationTasks.BookingSessionLocationID = BookingSessions.BookingSessionID
        WHERE BookingSessions.JobStartDT BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo
              AND BookingSessionEmployees.StartTime IS NOT NULL
              AND BookingSessionEmployees.EndTime IS NOT NULL

    UNION

    SELECT
    Employees.Forename + ' ' + Employees.Surname AS EmployeeName,
    Employees.WorkerReferenceID,
    LogData.DateOfWork AS WorkDate,
    NULL AS BookingStart,
    NULL AS BookingEnd,
    -- Gets the date from the date of work. Gets the time from the start time. Combines them. 
    CONVERT(datetime, LogData.DateOfWork + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, LogData.StartTime, 108)) AS LogStart,
    CONVERT(datetime, LogData.DateOfWork + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, LogData.EndTime, 108)) AS LogEnd
    FROM Employees
    INNER JOIN LogData ON Employees.EmployeeID = LogData.EmployeeID
    WHERE LogData.DateOfWork BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo
          AND LogData.StartTime IS NOT NULL
          AND LogData.EndTime IS NOT NULL
          AND LogData.StartTime <> LogData.EndTime -- Exclude entries where StartTime equals EndTime because these are all bonus Timesheets
) AS CombinedData
GROUP BY EmployeeName, WorkerReferenceID, WorkDate;
END
```

I haven't even got to the point where I can select the earliest start time from each day because it will select multiple records for the day.

I think i've got to the point where the SP is too complicated for what i'm trying to achieve and want some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could give us some example DDL/DML showcasing your problem, with a desired result. A good way to do this is with table variables: `DECALRE @WorkLog TABLE (WorkID INT IDENTITY, EmployeeID INT, StartDateTime...); INSERT INTO @WorkLog (EmployeeID, StartDateTime...) VALUES (1, '2023-09-07 08:46'...),....;`

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. The wall of code provided doesn't help us help you, though it provides some hints to possible problems. For example, it appears that no one can work over midnight.

Answer (score 0):

this example will give you an idea to get hours + min  of worked shift

```
DECLARE @dStart DATETIME = CAST('09/07/2023 8:01:00 AM' AS DATETIME),
    @dEnd DATETIME = CAST('09/07/2023 7:11:00 PM' AS DATETIME)

select CONVERT(TIME,@dEnd - @dStart) as ElapsedTime
```

[image]